# When can vsnprintf return 0?

Tags: c++, printf

When can `vsnprintf` function return `0`? It is behaving abnormally, it is returning `0`. Any environment dependency will be there?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

void func(int a,const char *format,...)
{
    int length = 0;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    printf("length is %d\n", length);
}

int main()
{
    func(10,"abcd");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler version are you using?  A quick test with VC++ 2013 shows `vsnprintf()` returning 4, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx#Anchor_1):

> The `vsnprintf` function returns the number of characters written, not
>   counting the terminating null character. If the buffer size specified
>   by count is not sufficiently large to contain the output specified by
>   `format` and `argptr`, **the return value of `vsnprintf` is the number of
>   characters that would be written**, not counting the null character, if
>   count were sufficiently large. If the return value is greater than
>   `count - 1`, the output has been truncated. A return value of `-1`
>   indicates that an encoding error has occurred.

So it only returns zero if it writes nothing. Since you are passing the buffer size as `0` then it can't write anything so it will always return `0` on success.

If you want to make the result anything else then you need to create a buffer.

```
void func(int a,const char *format,...)
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length = 0;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    length = vsnprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    printf("length is %d\n", length);
}
```

Comment: With GCC your example will produce the following warning: `warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]`.

Comment: I assume OP has something special planned for that `a`.

Comment: Note: "If the buffer size specified by count is not sufficiently large ... the return value of vsnprintf is the number of characters that would be written".  So in general `vsnprintf()` should not return 0 if the passed in buffer size is 0.

Comment: Hi,only 4 char I am passing to function.And also in some environment it is giving the proper value.

Comment: @Rohit: "also in some environment it is giving the proper value".  Can you update the question with details about which environment(s) have the correct behavior and which don't?  That is pretty important information that should be in the question. Please give version details on the toolchain and the platform.

Answer (score 0):

When the number of bytes it has written (or would write) would equal 0; in other words, when it has produced (would produce) no output.

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf):

> #### Return value
>
> 1-3) Number of characters written if successful or negative value if an error occurred.
>
> 4) Number of characters written if successful or negative value if an error occurred. If the resulting string gets truncated due to buf_size limit, function returns the total number of characters (not including the terminating null-byte) which would have been written, if the limit was not imposed.